# Prevent Xcode from changing the contents of a tab when a breakpoint is hit

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Let's say I have two classes, Unicorn and Rainbow. Unicorn.m is open in one tab in xcode, and I'm currently editing Rainbow.m, open in another tab. I have a breakpoint set in Unicorn.m. When I run my code, the Unicorn breakpoint gets hit, and my Rainbow tab, the tab I'm currently looking at, gets switched to Unicorn. So now I have Unicorn open in two tabs, and Rainbow open in none.

I would like for xcode to either:

a) look to see if there's currently a tab open which contains that breakpoint and if so, switch the current view to that tab

or:

b) open up a new tab

It's really annoying to me to have my current tab switched to another file. Is there any setting in xcode I can make to help me with this? Or should I submit a request to apple?

Answer (score 30):

I can help with b):

*Open preferences -> Behaviors -> Run Pauses:*

[image]

Check Show Tab and enter a Name for the new Tab you'd like to spawn when a breakpoint is reached. For this example it is **Breakpoint**.

Then, create a new tab by double clicking the empty area beside a tab (red arrow) or `+`. On the new tab, double click the name of the tab (green arrow) or press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and name it, no wonder, **Breakpoint**.

[image]

When the breakpoint is hit it'll open the Breakpoint tab or switch to it if it's already open.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a lot of manual steps. This behavior should really be baked in. Doesn't seem like that hard of logic to implement: "Is Doc X visible? If so, switch to that tab and skip to breakpoint line."

Comment: Yep, however I draw alot of comfort out of the fact that there is Appcode. I use XCode only for the Interface Builder nowadays.

Comment: This was helpful, however a solution to (a) would be really great.